# Analytical Function at Real infinity

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let's consider a function $f(z)$ analytical everywhere except at infinity. It's zero at real infinity $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=0$.

Is it true that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x+iy)=0$, where $x,y$ are reals?

Comment: $x\to 0$ isn't called infinity

Comment: What has the equality $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$ to do with infinity?

Comment: I'm very sorry, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$ does not imply $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x+iy)=0$ for $y \in \Bbb R$, a counterexample is
$$
 f(z) = \frac{\sin(z^2)}{z} \, .
$$ 
for $z \ne 0$, $f(0) = 0$. $f$ is an entire function. [Using](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Sine_with_a_complex_argument)
$$
 \sin(x+iy) = \sin (x) \cosh (y) + i \cos (x) \sinh (y)
$$
we get
$$
| \sin(x+iy) |^2 = \sin^2(x) + \sinh^2(y)
$$
and then
$$
|f(x+iy)|^2 = \left | \frac{\sin((x^2 - y^2) + i (2xy))}{x+iy} \right |^2
 = \frac{\sin^2(x^2-y^2) + \sinh^2(2xy)}{x^2+y^2}
$$
For $y=0$ we have
$$
 |f(x)|^2 = \frac{\sin^2(x^2)}{x^2} \le \frac{1}{x^2} \to 0
$$
for $x \to \pm \infty$. But for any $y \ne 0$
$$
|f(x+iy)|^2 \ge \frac{\sinh^2(2xy)}{x^2+y^2} \to \infty
$$
for $x \to \pm \infty$ because $\sinh$ grows exponentially, and therefore faster than any polynomial.